Trying to move Mongodb from HTTP to HTTPS and getting - com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream error
I am Trying to move Mongodb from HTTP to HTTPS
I have changed mongod.conf file
net:
port: 27017
  bindIp: <required host names>
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: /path/mongodb.pem
    CAFile: /path/mongodb.pem

security:
 authorization: "enabled"

**The command to connect with mongodb is **
mongo --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile path/mongodb.pem --tlsCAFile path/mongodb.pem --host <host_name> --port <port> -u <username> -p <password> --authenticationDatabase <database_name> 
Code level changes:
String connectionString = String.format(
        String connectionString = String.format(
                "mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?tls=true&tlsCAFile=%s&tlsCertificateKeyFile=%s",
                "mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s",
                username, password, mongoHost, mongoPort, mongoDB, tlsCAFile, tlsCertificateKeyFile
                username, password, mongoHost, mongoPort, mongoDB
        );


application.properties
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<databasename>?tls=true&tlsCAFile=/path/mongodb.pem&tlsCertificateKeyFile=/path/mongodb.pem&connectTimeoutMS=60000&socketTimeoutMS=60000

But while testing after making these configurations i am getting
"level":"INFO ","exchange":"?","routingKey":"?","message":"No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=:, type=UNKNOWN, state=**********, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out","stacktrace":""}
I am able to connect to mongodb both in mongo compass and from terminal, but not from java app. please help me with it
What might be the possible solution or cause for this issue?

Does the mongodb log offer any clues?

These are mongodb logs -  {"t":{"$date":"2024-11-08T02:14:07.394+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22988,   "ctx":"conn1967","msg":"Error receiving request from client. Ending connection from remote","attr":{"error":{"code":141,"codeName":"SSLHandshakeFailed","errmsg":"The server is configured to only allow SSL connections"},"remote":"172.25.48.30:58740", "connectionId":1967}}{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-08T02:14:07.395+05:30"}, "s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn1967","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"172.25.48.30:58740","connectionId":1967,"connectionCount":3}}

If that remote IP matches where you are coming from, that looks like the client is not actually using TLS

Yes, The client didn’t support .pem files, so I converted them to p12 format and updated the SSL configurations in the Java code. Now the SSL handshake is successfully happening.
